# Last item of ListView filling available space

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView, which takes from 30 to 100%(which makes it scrollable) of the screen height. I want the last element of this ListView to have as much available height as its possible. Moreover - when there are no other items - it still has to be visible

Example:
If ListView(with no last element) takes 30% of the screen, then the last element should take 70% of the screen.

If ListView takes 100%(and you have to scroll it down) then the last element should have as much height as other items.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not the default behavior of the `ListView`, and I'm not sure if you can do what you propose (at least not easily).

The common behavior of a `ListView` is to distribute its dimensions to the ones defined in its layout. That means that rows will have a minimal height/width, but afterwards scrolling will be enabled and the items will be equal in height.

One way you might try to accomplish this is extending an `ArrayAdapter` (from your question it's not clear if you're already doing), and implement that behavior in the `getView()` method.

`ArrayAdapter` doesn't have a `getLastItem()` method so you'll need to keep track somehow of which is your last item in your list: keeping a copy of the items to display or just defining a public method that would be called from your `Activity` or `Fragment` to tell them it's the last item, and in your `getView()` method do something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
  // convertView references to the current row being rendered
  if (convertView == myLastItem)
    convertView.setHeight(myLastRowsHeight);

  ...
}
```

To know the space left by your layout, you can get the display height and substract the `ListView`'s height minus the last row minus any other `View`s you could have in the same layout.

```
final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
// params.height will have the screen's height
params.height = (int) (size.y * 0.8);

int myLastRowsHeight = params.height - (myListView.getHeight() * (number_of_rows - 1) - my_other_views;
```